# List View Multiple Case Owner Update

Tags: javascript, custom-button, list-view

I have used the below piece of code to select multiple cases from list view and update case owner. But it does not update the owner when I am selecting multiple cases while it works when I select only one case.

I had also added a line of code (  //   sforce.connection.update([caseUpdate]); ) to test the beahviour and now multiple cases started updating. But updating each case one after another involves delay.

I wonder why Am I not able to Update the case in array. Please suggest.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}
var records =     {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)};
var updateRecords = [];
var userId = "{!$User.Id}";

if (records[0] == null) {
    alert("Please Select atleast one Case")
} else {
    //Get more info on the cases that were selected and generate a query out of it
    var queryResults = sforce.connection.retrieve("CaseNumber, Id, OwnerId,Owner.Type", "Case", records);

    var casesAccepted = "";
    var casesRejected = "";
    //Iterate through the returned results
    for (var caseIndex=0;caseIndex<queryResults.length;caseIndex++) 
        {
        var caseObj = queryResults[caseIndex];
        //If it's already owned by a user, add it to the reject pile
        if (caseObj.Owner.Type=='User') 
                {
            casesRejected += caseObj.CaseNumber + " ";
        } 
                else {
            //Otherwise accept it
            var caseUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Case");
            caseUpdate.Id = caseObj.Id;
            caseUpdate.OwnerId = '{!User.Id}';
            caseUpdate.Status = 'In Progress';
            caseUpdate.Button_Clicked__C = 'True';
            updateRecords.push(caseUpdate);
                     *****//   sforce.connection.update([caseUpdate]);*****
            casesAccepted += caseObj.CaseNumber + " ";
             }


    } 

    //Give the user some feedback
    var alertText = "";

    if (updateRecords.length>0) {
        sforce.connection.update(updateRecords);
        alertText += "The Ownership For Selected Cases Has Changed To You:\n"+casesAccepted;
    }

    if (casesRejected!="") {
        alertText += "\n The Selected Case(s)Are Now Transferred To You:   :\n"+casesRejected;
    }

    alert(alertText);
    //Reload the list view to show what he now owns
    parent.window.location.reload();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2703132, I believe replacing your code "sforce.connection.update([caseUpdate]);"  with "sforce.connection.update(updateRecords);" will solve your issue.

```
for (var caseIndex = 0; caseIndex < queryResults.length; caseIndex++) 
{
    var caseObj = queryResults[caseIndex];
    //If it's already owned by a user, add it to the reject pile
    if (caseObj.Owner.Type == 'User') {
        casesRejected += caseObj.CaseNumber + " ";
    } 
    else {
        //Otherwise accept it
        var caseUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Case");
        caseUpdate.Id = caseObj.Id;
        caseUpdate.OwnerId = '{!User.Id}';
        caseUpdate.Status = 'In Progress';
        caseUpdate.Button_Clicked__C = 'True';
        updateRecords.push(caseUpdate);

        casespted += caseObj.CaseNumber + " ";
    }
}
sforce.connection.update(updateRecords);
```